# How can I plot the circular movement of a particle given it's angular velocity and radius?

Tags: matlab, plot

The question is:

> First part. Create a function drawMUC.m that draws the circular path of a particle knowing its angular velocity `ω` and the radius of rotation `r`. Recall the meaning of the period of a circular motion. The Cartesian equations are: `x=r*cos(ω*t)` and `y=r*sin(ω*t)`.

> Second part. Once done, add the velocity vector to the trajectory at each point with the quiver command, using the velocity equations: `v_x=-rω*sen(ω*t)` and `x_y=rω*cos(ω*t)`.

**Attempt.** So this is my code for the first part and then the attempt to the second one

```
function dibujaMUC(w,r)

t=1:(2*pi)/(w);
y=r.*sin(w.*t);
x=r.*cos(w*t);
plot(x,y)

>>dibujaMUC(0.1,2)
```

And adding for the second part:

```
function dibujaMUC(w,r)

t=1:(2*pi)/(w);
y=r.*sin(w.*t);
x=r.*cos(w*t);
plot(x,y)
hold on
vx=-r.*w.*sin(w.*t);
vy=r.*w.*cos(w.*t);
quiver(vx,vy)

>> dibujaMUC(0.1,2)
```

But then I get this, which I don't think it's exactly what needed:

[Description of what plot I get after plugging the second part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WD5xz.png)

[Issue where the circle doesn't fully close, zoomed in image of the suggested plot in the posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Y4sR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I would expect t to start at 0, not 1. Also, you need to tell quiver to attach the direction arrows to the points using a different syntax. E.g.,

```
t=0:(2*pi)/(w);
   :
quiver(x,y,vx,vy)
```

That being said, the plot would probably look more meaningful if you only attached the direction arrows to a subset of the points or to points that are spaced out more. E.g., this doesn't meet the instructions you were given because you are not plotting the quiver "at each point," but it certainly makes a more readable plot:

```
n = 5;
quiver(x(1:n:end),y(1:n:end),vx(1:n:end),vy(1:n:end))
```

Comment: also one last question, why does my circle have a missing end? when you plot it doesn't fully close the circle, that's just details but I was wondering about it. (I have edited my post to show a picture of it, if it's not clear enough already)

Comment: The reason the circle doesn't close is because of the way you form t. Using the colon operator with fractional numbers doesn't guarantee that the "last" number gets into the result because of floating point arithmetic effects. In your case 2*pi/w didn't make it. To make sure that last desired number gets into the result, form t a different way. E.g. t = linspace(0,2*pi/w,361) would create 361 evenly spaced points between 0 and 2*pi/w including the endpoints.

Comment: To learn MATLAB online, I suggest the MATLAB Onramp on their website. https://www.mathworks.com/learn/tutorials/matlab-onramp.html